# Como clonar objetos em Python?

Tags: python, orientação-a-objetos, classes, clone

Em algumas linguagens, além de podermos instanciar uma classe para construção de um determinado objeto, podemos também clonar uma instância já existente, caso queiramos um objeto com as mesmas caracteristicas da instância atual, porém sem alterar o estado da original.

Por exemplo, se eu quisesse modificar uma cópia de um objeto `DateTime` em PHP, para usar a mesma informação da data do objeto dessa instância, porém tendo uma instância apenas com o horário modificado, eu poderia fazer assim:

```
  $date = new Date('2015-01-01 00:00:00');

  $date2 = clone $date;

  // não precisei redefinir a data, mas só a hora

  $date2->setTime(23, 59, 59);
```

Acima, não foi necessário criar uma nova instância com a informação da data, mas apenas clonei e modifiquei para o horário que precisava.

É claro que acima foi apenas um exemplo, mas existem ainda outros casos que a criação de uma nova instância de um objeto poderia se tornar complicada, devida a dependências de um objeto. Aí podemos clonar para ter as mesmas informações num novo objeto, porém sem modificar o original.

Em Python também percebo que tudo (ou quase tudo até, onde percebi) são objetos. Porém, em se tratando de instâncias de classes, existe alguma forma de clonar objetos como se faz em PHP?

Parar criar uma instância de uma classe em Python não precisamos de um operador `new`, como em PHP.

Então como seria a forma de se clonar um Objeto em Python? Existe um operador específico para isso?

Outra coisa é que em PHP podemos usar um método mágico dentro da classe chamado `__clone` para determinar o comportamento daquela classe quando um clone for criado.

E em Python? Existe algum método especial para poder modificar o comportamento da classe em relação a criação de um clone?

Comment: Wallace estará à procura de algo como https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/copy.html, http://www.python-course.eu/deep_copy.php?

Comment: Tipo isso. Interessante é saber que o Python resolveu isso com um módulo...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Em Python, a forma mais comum de fazer isso é usando o módulo `copy` da biblioteca padrão.

Se `dt` é um `datetime`, você pode criar uma cópia fazendo:

```
from copy import copy
dt2 = copy(dt)
```

(* veja última sessão d respostas sobre o `datetime` especificamente)

O módulo tamem tem o método `deepcopy`, e a grande diferença é que enquanto o `copy` só vai copiar a instância - e manter referências internas para os objetos que sejam apontados pelos atributos.

Em particular para estruturas de dados com várias listas e diconários aninhados - o `deepcopy` vai fazer uma cópia recursiva de cada lista e dicionário na sua estrutura - enquanto que o `copy` vai criar uma cópia só do objeto passado, mas manter todas as referências internas.

O `copy` e `deepcopy` quebram um galhão - mas poderiam ser implementados em uma forma genérica, usando Python puro, com poucas linhas. O interessante da inguagem Python é que os objetos são definidos de forma a permitir introspecção, e em geral não violam essas regras.  Portando, se você, por exemplo, quisesse copiar uma instância de um objeto genérico, e não dispussesse do `copy.copy` poderia: (1) chamar o método `__new__` da classe do objeto explicitamente, (2) atualizar o atributo `__dict__` da nova instância para ser igual o `__dict__` do objeto copiado:

```
obj = MinhaClasse()
obj.a = 20
obj.b = 30

obj2 = type(obj).__new__(type(obj))
obj2.__dict__.update(obj.__dict__)
print (obj2.a, obj2.b)
```

Saída:

```
20 30
```

Mas o copy ainda cobre vários corner cases, podendo copiar objetos que tenham atributos que não estão no `__dict__`, e etc...
(Só para constar - o mecanismo normal para instanciar uma classe chama o método `__new__` e logo em seguida o `__init__` de uma classe. Por isso quando criamos uma classe, em geral personalizamos só o `__init__` - ao chamar só o `__new__`, o novo objeto não é inicializado com nenhum valor. Ao copiar os atributos, que ficam no `__dict__`, você tem seu "clone")

**datetime**: Note que o objeto `datetime` da biblitoeca parão do Python é imutável, então você não pode alterar o horário dele. Isso é necessário para que os datetimes possam ser usados como chaves de dicionários. Se precisar criar um outro datetime, mantendo a data e mudando o horário como no seu exemplo, precisará fazer uma função auxiliar que faça isso 'manualmente':

```
def changetime(dt, new_time):
    return  datetime.datetime(dt.year, dt.month, dt.day, new_time.hour, new_time.minute, new_time.second)
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta. O DateTime até que não me preocupou muito, pois foi o primeiro exemplo que me veio a mente quando citei sobre PHP. A resposta está bem explicativa, vou marcá-la como útil :p